# R rvest keeping italics in text when scraping

Tags: r, rvest

I'm looking to scrape some message from an online message board. 
Currently I am using:

```
html_nodes(conv,'.talk-post.message')  %>%
  html_text(trim = TRUE)
```

For the message:
     *I'm back now and slowly getting back to speed.*

This gives:
     "\nI'm back now and slowly getting back to speed.\n"

Which works fine, but removes all html formatting. I would like to retain an indication of where the text has  italics tags (similarly for underlining and bold).

I appreciate I could use toString.XMLNode instead, but then that keeps all html tags, not just the three required.

```
"{xml_nodeset (1)}\n[1] <div class=\"talk-post  message\">\\n<p><i>I'm back now and slowly getting back to speed.</i><br>
```

Are there any more elegant solutions to this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the XML library for get all the string in the div.

```
> library(XML)
> txtNode <- "<div><i>Hello</i></div><div><b>World</b></div><div><b><i>!</i></b></div>"
> html <- htmlParse(txtNode)
> html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><body>
<div><i>Hello</i></div>
<div><b>World</b></div>
<div><b><i>!</i></b></div>
</body></html>

> 
> lNode <- getNodeSet(html, "//div")
> lNode
[[1]]
<div>
  <i>Hello</i>
</div> 

[[2]]
<div>
  <b>World</b>
</div> 

[[3]]
<div>
  <b>
    <i>!</i>
  </b>
</div> 

attr(,"class")
[1] "XMLNodeSet"
> 
> lapply(lNode, function(x) toString.XMLNode(x[[1]]))
[[1]]
[1] "<i>Hello</i> "

[[2]]
[1] "<b>World</b> "

[[3]]
[1] "<b>\n  <i>!</i>\n</b> "
```